Is there any reason to have lechem mishnah when eating cake?
I heard that there's an inyan to have lechem mishnah even when eating cake. Does anyone know of a source for this?

If you're קובע סעודה on mezonos? I think I've heard that too.

@Shmosel if you are קובע סעודה then you need to make hamotzi

For קידוש במקום סעודה mezonos is enough.

@Shmosel that's true (according to some opinions) but I don’t think it’s referred to as קובע סעודה

If one is using pat haba’ah bekisanin for קידוש במקום סעודה, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 77:17 writes that one should use two “loaves”.

Why does it matter if you are using it for קידוש במקום סעודה vs eating in the afternoon for fun?

@DoubleAA the same thought occurred to me. Maybe R Ganzfried couldn’t imagine eating for fun?

Maybe he thought it's a din in seudah not in eating (eg. bread less than a kezayis maybe doesn't need)
